# How to show a JSON array in an array with a nested v-data-table in a v-data-table from vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I got the array below and I don't know a more elegant way of displaying it than unpacking and packing it.

```
employeeList: [{
    lastname: '',
    firsname: '',
    date: [],
    status: [],
    starttime: [],
    endtime: [],
    id: ''
}]
```

or

```
employeeList: [{
    lastname: '',
    firsname: '',
    time: [{
        date: [],
        status: [],
        starttime: [],
        endtime: []
    }],
    id: ''
}]
```

I would like to use a nested `v-data-table` and just redraw the last- and `firstname`
Any ideas?

The way I tried it looks like I hacked the table to pieces:

https://codepen.io/jangirke/pen/xxKjRxO